# Hierarchical bootstrapping in R

Tags: r

I have a specific way I'd like to bootstrap the following survival data ("mydata"; this is just a sample of the full data set):

```
cup surv
100-9   0
100-9   0
100-9   1
100-9   1
101-9   0
101-9   0
101-9   0
101-9   0
51-1    0
51-1    1
51-1    1
51-1    1
```

Each row is an individual that either lived (surv="1") or died (surv="0"). Individuals were clustered four per cup. I'd like each iteration of the bootstrap to sample just one random individual, no more, from each cup, and estimate the mean and sd. The next iteration would again sample one individual per cup, which may or may not be the same individual sampled in the first iteration.

So far, I've had success only sampling randomly with replacement across all cups, so that each iteration might count two separate individuals from the same cup, while sampling zero from another cup. Here is that code:

```
library(boot)
surv.mean = function(x, indices) {
return( mean( x[indices] ) )
}
surv.boot <-  boot(mydata$surv, surv.mean, 10000)
boot.ci(surv.boot)
```

I do not think cluster analysis is the right way to go, I think of this as nested subsampling (with restrictions?). Please let me know if you have a helpful hint!

Thank you.

P.S. For bonus awesome points, how would one then model bootstrapped survival estimates among groups using logistic regression [preferably using glm(, family = binomial)], e.g.:

```
group cup   surv
A     100-9 0
A     100-9 0
A     100-9 1
A     100-9 1
B     101-9 0
B     101-9 0
B     101-9 0
B     101-9 0
C     51-1  0
C     51-1  1
C     51-1  1
C     51-1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
subsample <- mydata %>%
                group_by(cup) %>%
                sample_n(1)
```